# ¿Cómo compartir información entre controladores en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Mi aplicación tiene la siguiente estructura:

- APP

  - css
  - js

    - main.js
    - MenuGestionStockController.js
    - SearchStockController.js
  - Scripts
  - views

    - menu-stock.html
    - search-stock.html

MenuGestionStockController.js:

```
        var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.factory("sharedMenu", function() {

        var MenuSelected = "None";

        MenuSelected.getMenuSelected = function() {
            return MenuSelected;
                },
        MenuSelected.setMenuSelected = function (value) {
            MenuSelected = value;
        }

        return MenuSelected;
        })

        app.controller("menuGestionStockController", function ($scope, sharedMenu) {

        $scope.sharedMenu = sharedMenu;
        console.log("Menu OK");
        console.log("sharedMenu: " + $scope.sharedMenu);


    })
```

Al cambiar de vista se carga el controlador SearchStockController.js en el cual me gustaría tener los datos de MenuSelected ya que me gustaría guardar la información del menú seleccionado por el usuario.

SearchStockController.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app");

app.controller("searchStockController",  function ($scope, sharedMenu) {

$scope.filtros = [{
    nombre: "Número de serie",
    campos: ["Nº Serie", "Cliente", "Referencia", "Dioptría", "Fecha Envío"]
}, {
    nombre: "Referencia",
    campos: ["Cliente", "Referencia", "Nº Serie", "Dioptría", "Fecha Envío"]
}, {
    nombre: "Cliente",
    campos: ["Referencia", "Nº Serie", "Dioptría", "Fecha Envío"]
}, {
    nombre: "Fecha de caducidad",
    campos: ["Cliente", "Referencia", "Nº Serie", "Dioptría", "Fecha Envío"]
}];

console.log("searchStockController - OK");
console.log("Filtros: " + $scope.filtros[0].campos)
});
```

La aplicación ejectua y al acceder a la vista search-stock.html (que redirige desde menu-stock.html) aparece el siguiente error:

[image: Error de Angular al inyectar el module]

Alguien más ha tenido problema? Se trata de un error de inyección en module? esto definiendo mal el controller?

Quiero destacar que los controladores estan en ficheros Js ya que todas las soluciones que encuentro trabajan sobre el mismo archivo, es por eso?

Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución. Se trataba de un problema a la hora de realizar los imports en el html. Llamaba antes al controlador que al angular.module.

Ha quedado así:

```
<script src="../../js/MenuGestionStockController.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/SearchStockController.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

con un factory puedes compartir informacion entre controladores..

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Comment: Hola Luis, puedo compartir variables y/o funciones como bien dices pero puedo realizar modificaciones en un controlador y que esos cambios se reflejen en los otros controladores?

Un ejemplo muy básico: Si en una factory existe value = 0; Controlador1 podría incrementar ese valor en 1 y luego un Controlador2 incrementar ese valor 1?